# Не обновляется jquery DOM после добавления клонированной строки

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, dom

Таблица и первая строка создается в partial view (ASP.NET MVC), и добавляется на форму с помощью Ajax. После чего я клонирую эту строку в таблице (id таблицы #containerOCR) и добавляю на форму. 
Все работает, однако после добавления перестает функционировать валидация  и datepicker, зато когда нажимаешь на добавленные клонированием элементы на которых должен быть завязан datepicker, то он (datepicker) срабатывает у первоначального элемента. Атр. name всех элементов я меняю соотв. образом. 
Я склоняюсь к мысли, что клонирование происходит не полное, а по ссылке. Возможно кто-то знает, как правильно подправить код для этого случая.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $('body').on('click', '#addProduct', function (e) {
                addProduct();
            });
        });

        function addProduct() {
            var $table = $('#containerOCR'), //Таблица
                $row = $table.find('#trOCR').clone(true), //строка с id = trOCR
                $prodFound = $('#ProductsFound').val();//Значение для добавления в <input GoodName>

            if ($table.length > 0 && $row.length != 0 && $prodFound.length > 2){
                var $countRow = $table.length;
                var $rowNew = $row.first(); //Первая строка
                //The value of the hidden field (is transferred as model)
                $rowNew.find('input[name$=".GoodName"]').val($prodFound).attr('name', '[' + ($countRow) + '].GoodName');
                //Displayed value
                $rowNew.find('#GoodName').text($prodFound);
                $rowNew.find('input[name$=".Quantity"]').val('0').attr('name', '[' + ($countRow) + '].Quantity');
                $rowNew.find('input[name$=".Price"]').val('0').attr('name', '[' + ($countRow) + '].Price');
                $rowNew.find('input[name$=".Date"]').attr('name', '[' + ($countRow) + '].Date');

                $rowNew.find('span[data-valmsg-for$=".Quantity"]').attr('data-valmsg-for', '[' + ($countRow) + '].Quantity');
                $rowNew.find('span[data-valmsg-for$=".Price"]').attr('data-valmsg-for', '[' + ($countRow) + '].Price');
                $rowNew.find('span[data-valmsg-for$=".Date"]').attr('data-valmsg-for', '[' + ($countRow) + '].Date');

                $('#containerOCR tr:last').after($rowNew);
            }
            else if ($prodFound.length > 2) {
                var $findProduct = $("#ProductsFound").val();
                var $link = "@Url.Action("AddProduct", "Home")?product=";
                $('#shoppingListResult').load($link + "" + encodeURIComponent($findProduct));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Из описания, похоже на то, что валидация и datepicker загружаются при создании дерева DOM,и добавляет event для существующих элементов. Ты добавляешь элементы асинхронно после загрузки и инициализации валидатора и datepicker-a, и они просто не знают что их нужно тоже учитывать при определенных действиях.

Проверь на что реагируют эти скрипты, пропагация должна решить проблему.

Что-то типа:

```js
$('#containerOCR').on('click', 'input[name$=".GoodName"]', function(event){
  validation();
  datepickr();
});
```

Comment: Я согласен с вами, скорее всего проблема именно в этом, т.к. при следующем вызове метода, значение: var $countRow = $table.length;

Comment: Остается неизменным и равно единице, только я не знаю как тут лучше сделать пропагацию. К сожалению ваш пример не заработал.

Comment: Вы используете сторонние библиотеки datepicker.js  и validate.js (или что-то типа того), правильно я понимаю? Нужно чуть больше информации.

Если подгружаются библиотеки, то нужно в них копаться и переделывать под себя, т.е. скорее всего инициализируются в момент загрузки DOM, проверяют наличие по ключевым словам / тегам / атрибутам, и добавляют функции к событию.

Comment: Все верно, насчет библиотек. Первая строка таблицы подгружается через partialView ajax-м и с ней соответственно все ок, потом я ее клонирую вместе со всей разметкой, пробовал clone(true) и без, если ставить true, то при нажатии на клонированный элемент событие срабатывает у родителя. Имена и id я меняю перед добавлением в таблицу, но похоже это не имеет значения.

Answer (score 0):

DatePicker мне удалось завести, однако, после этого он не цепляет обновленный код настроек в отдельном файле для datepicker. Ну да ладно, а вот валидация не завелась и это странно, так как если добавить на форму больше элементов через контрол @Ajax.ActionLink(), а не jquery код, то она работает. 
По поводу datepicker, я подкоректировал id, что бы он был действительно уникален для каждого input с Date (до этого я сделал ошибку и присвоил одинаковый id всем input), но этого мало, я так же удалил и передобавил dayepicker для каждого создаваемого поля .Date. 
Изменения: 
**$rowNew.find('input[name$=".Date"]').each(function () {
                $(this).attr({
                    id: count
                });
            });
            count++;** 
и             **$rowNew.find('input[name$=".Date"]').attr('name', '[' + (count) + '].Date').removeClass('hasDatepicker').
datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });// And re-apply;**

```
var count = 0;
function addProduct() {
    var $table = $('#containerOCR'),
        $rowNew = $table.find('#trOCR').first().clone(),
    $prodFound = $('#ProductsFound').val();

    //The table contains the rows, rows contains the columns, the search string is not empty, more than 2 characters
    if ($table.length > 0 && $rowNew.length != 0 && $prodFound.length > 2) {

        $rowNew.find('input[name$=".Date"]').each(function () {
            $(this).attr({
                id: count
            });
        });
        count++;
        //The value of the hidden field (is transferred as model)
        $rowNew.find('input[name$=".GoodName"]').val($prodFound).attr('name', '[' + (count) + '].GoodName');
        //Displayed value
        $rowNew.find('#GoodName').text($prodFound);
        $rowNew.find('input[name$=".Quantity"]').val('0').attr('name', '[' + (count) + '].Quantity');
        $rowNew.find('input[name$=".Price"]').val('0').attr('name', '[' + (count) + '].Price');
        $rowNew.find('input[name$=".Date"]').attr('name', '[' + (count) + '].Date').removeClass('hasDatepicker'). // Remove datepicker
            datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });// And re-apply;

        $rowNew.find('span[data-valmsg-for$=".Quantity"]').attr('data-valmsg-for', '[' + (count) + '].Quantity');
        $rowNew.find('span[data-valmsg-for$=".Price"]').attr('data-valmsg-for', '[' + (count) + '].Price');
        $rowNew.find('span[data-valmsg-for$=".Date"]').attr('data-valmsg-for', '[' + (count) + '].Date');
        //document.getElementById("containerOCR").insertRow(-1).innerHTML = $rowNew.html();

        $('#containerOCR tr:last').after($rowNew);
        //redrawForm();
    }
    else if ($prodFound.length > 2) {
        var $findProduct = $("#ProductsFound").val();
        var $link = "@Url.Action("AddProduct", "Home")?product=";
        $('#shoppingListResult').load($link + "" + encodeURIComponent($findProduct));
    }
}
```